# Expected value for the probability function $p * (1 - p)^{n - 1}$

Tags: probability

$p * (1 - p)^{n - 1}$ is the function I came up with for this problem:

```
If player one has a p probability of winning and stops playing after 
he or she wins against player two, what is the probability that exactly 
n games are played?
```

I know expected value $= x_1p_1 + x_2p_2 + ... x_np_n$

How would I go about finding $E[x]$ for this, where $x$ is the number of games played? I can't wrap my mind around how the equation can be applied in this case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $P(X = n) = p(1-p)^{n-1}$  (Note: $n-1$ losses before victory on the $n^{th}$ game.)

So $P(X \leq n) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n p(1-p)^{k-1}$

$\therefore E[X] = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k p (1-p)^{k-1} = \dfrac 1 p$

Let $q=1-p$

$\therefore E[X] = (1-q)\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k q^{k-1}$

$\therefore E[X] = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k q^{k-1} - \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k q^k$

$\therefore E[X] = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (k+1) q^{k} - \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty k q^k$

$\therefore E[X] = 1 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty q^{k} = 1 + q + q^2 + q^3 + \ldots$

Now when $|q|<1 , \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty q^k = \dfrac 1{1-q}$

$$\therefore E[X] = \dfrac{1}{p}$$